# Paypal Javascript SDK - buttons not visible on mobile

Tags: javascript, paypal

I am using the javascript SDK from Paypal to create buttons.  Everything works great on the desktop however on mobile phones the buttons do not show up. From what I am gathering, there is no change the the Paypal script needed to render the buttons as Paypal handles that.  It appears that the paypal.Buttons portion does not execute.  I can change the label up until that point using javascript.

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxx&disable-funding=venmo,paylater&currency=USD" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>


<div id="smart-button-container">
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <div style="margin-bottom: 1.25rem;">
            <p><label id="item-optionslbl" style="font:larger;font-weight:bold">Dec 9th -  7:30PM- 22.50 USD</label></p>
            <p>Select the number of tickets below for December 9th</p>
            <select style="visibility: visible" id="quantitySelect">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="paypal-button-container7778894"></div>

    </div>
</div>


<script>
    function initPayPalButton() {
        var shipping = 0;
        var itemdesc0 = "It's a Wonderful Life Dec 9 at 7:30 PM";
        var itemOptions = itemdesc0;
        var quantity = parseInt(20);
        var quantitySelect = document.querySelector("#smart-button-container #quantitySelect");
        //if (!isNaN(quantity)) {
        //    quantitySelect.style.visibility = "visible";
        //}
        var orderDescription = "It's a Wonderful Life Dec 9";
        if (orderDescription === '') {
            orderDescription = 'Item';
        }
        paypal.Buttons({
            style: {
                shape: 'rect',
                color: 'gold',
                layout: 'vertical',
                label: 'paypal',

            },

            createOrder: function (data, actions) {
                var selectedItemDescription = itemdesc0;
                var selectedItemPrice = 22.50;
                var tax = (0 === 0 || false) ? 0 : (selectedItemPrice * (parseFloat(0) / 100));
                if (quantitySelect.options.length > 0) {
                    quantity = parseInt(quantitySelect.options[quantitySelect.selectedIndex].value);
                } else {
                    quantity = 1;
                }

                tax *= quantity;
                tax = Math.round(tax * 100) / 100;
                var priceTotal = quantity * selectedItemPrice;
                priceTotal = Math.round(priceTotal * 100) / 100;
                var itemTotalValue = Math.round((selectedItemPrice * quantity) * 100) / 100;

                return actions.order.create({
                    purchase_units: [{
                        description: orderDescription,
                        amount: {
                            currency_code: 'USD',
                            value: priceTotal,
                            breakdown: {
                                item_total: {
                                    currency_code: 'USD',
                                    value: itemTotalValue,
                                },
                                tax_total: {
                                    currency_code: 'USD',
                                    value: tax,
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        items: [{
                            name: selectedItemDescription,
                            unit_amount: {
                                currency_code: 'USD',
                                value: selectedItemPrice,
                            },
                            quantity: quantity
                        }]
                    }]
                });
            },
            onApprove: function (data, actions) {
                return actions.order.capture().then(function (orderData) {

                    // Full available details
                    console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));

                    // Or go to another URL:
                    actions.redirect('webpage.html');

                });
            },
            onError: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            },
        }).render('#paypal-button-container7778894');
    }
    initPayPalButton();
</script>
```

Comment: By mobile do you mean a full browser view or a webview?

Comment: just the webpage on my iphone . that page works on my desktop but the button does not appear on any phone

Comment: Is it reproducible with client-id=test ? Host it somewhere that can be tested